# Differences between "fill_parent" and "wrap_content"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to this, I would say what is the difference between `width = "fill_parent"` and `width = "wrap_content"`?

Answer (score 1):

`fill_parent` will make the width or height of the element to be as large as the parent element, in other words, the container.

`wrap_content` will make the width or height be as large as needed to contain the elements within it.

Comment: well I is much clearer, thanks for answering :D

Answer (score 1):

From android docs.-

> **FILL_PARENT** (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which
> means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
>
> **WRAP_CONTENT**, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content > (plus padding)